# How to limit the moving range of interactive markers?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm following the [Interactive Markers](http://wiki.ros.org/rviz/Tutorials/Interactive%20Markers%3A%20Getting%20Started) tutorial, is there anyway that we could set a limit to the interactive markers? For example, we just want to move them within some specific closed region.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/251988/how-to-limit-the-moving-range-of-interactive-markers?/) by [Huskinu](https://answers.ros.org/users/28894/huskinu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2017-01-15

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2017-01-15**:
I've seen this done, so I know it's possible, but I'm not sure how it was done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ok, I managed to update the marker pose back to last saved position if I detect it is moved (by user) out of pre-defined limited region. We can set it in a callback insalled for the interactive marker server!

---

Originally posted by [Huskinu](https://answers.ros.org/users/28894/huskinu/) with karma: 16 on 2017-01-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0